# Do I need to remove previously built, unused Docker images / containers ?

Tags: image, docker, containers

On typing `Docker images` and `Docker ps -a` in terminal, 
I have a long list of previously built, no-longer-in-use Docker images. What is the disadvantage of keeping them there? What kind of harm can they cause?

Is it a better idea to remove the unused images/containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no harm, per-se, in having these images - but they do take up space on your hard drive, and if you aren't using them, keeping them is just a waste of resources.

Comment: Is the container or the image taking up space? More than half of the old images are build from the same base image. I guess they are not taking so much space then?

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C The image takes up space. The container is the runtime - since you aren't running anything, there is no container. You can use `du` to see how much space they take up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!     Just `du` ?  can you give me the full command sentence?

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C `du -h /path/to/file`

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea, but carefull, don't remove images with which you current work, but if you finished with images and container better remove it, because they taking space.

For remove all images and containers use `docker system prune -a`

```
# Delete all containers
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
# Delete all images
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
```